# how to cut part of string

Tags: vb.net, string

How to cut part from this string...

```
"abb.c.d+de.ee+f.xxx+qaa.+.,,s,"
```

... where i know position by this:

Result is always between "." (left side of result) and "+" (right side).
I know number of "." from left side and number of "+" from right side, to delimit resulting string.

Problem is right side, cause i need to count "+" from end.

Say...

from left side:  begining is at 4th "."
( this is easy ), result is =

```
"xxx+qaa.+.,,s,"
```

from right side:  end is at second "+" from end!

```
"xxx[here]+qaa.+.,,s,"
```

result is =

```
"xxx"
```

I try to do this myself with .substring and .indexOf, but with no success...

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `StrReverse` function to reverse the character sequence and then count `+` from the left (using the same method as counting the `.`).

Comment: Exactly. `StrReverse`, i totaly forgot about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To find the start of the substring, loop through the string from the left. Count the number of `.`s you have seen and stop when you've hit the number you want. Store the index in some variable like `start`.

Similarly to find the end of the substring, loop from the right and count `+`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using Regex:

```
Dim r As New Regex("^(.*\.){4}(?<value>.*)(\+.*){2}$")
Dim m As Match = r.Match("abb.c.d+de.ee+f.xxx+qaa.+.,,s,")
Dim result As String = m.Result("${value}")
```

**Explanation**

- `^`   Indicates the beginning of the string
- `(.*\.){4}`  This means any character (`.`) repeated any number of times (`*`) followed by a period (`\.`).  The period has to be escaped with the backslash because otherwise the period would be the any-character wildcard. The `.*\.` is enclosed in `(){4}` to say that pattern must repeat four times.
- `(?<value>.*)`  This specifies the placeholder for the text we are after.  `value` is the name we are assigning to it.  The `.*` specifies that the value is any number of any characters.
- `(\+.*){2}`  This means a plus character (has to be escaped) followed by any number of any characters, repeated twice.
- `$`  Indicates the end of the string

Comment: thanks, but regex is too complicated for me right now. Once i will try to learn..

Comment: No problem.  It's good that you only use what you understand.  It's a sign of a bad programmer when they just copy and paste a bunch of code that they don't understand and just get it to work.  It never works out well in the end.  I don't have a lot of experience with Regex myself, mainly because haven't had much need for it yet, but I would recommend getting comfortable with it at some point.  It's superior in the sense that you can store all that logic as a simple string setting (if necessary).  And, while it's ugly to read, it's actually much easier to write than you'd expect.